# How many associative binary operations there are on a finite set?

Tags: group-theory, semigroups

I am studying Scott's book *Group Theory*. In the Exercise $1.1.17$ he asks us to show that if $S$ is a set and $|S|=n$, then there are $n^{\frac{n^{2}+n}{2}}$ commutative binary operations on $S$. But he doesn't talk about how many associative binary operations there are on a finite set.

Is there an answer to that question? I mean, how many associative binary operations there are on a finite set?

Comment: Knowing how many associative binary operations there are on a set with $n$ elements would tell you how many non-isomorphic semigroup structures there are on a set with $n$ elements. As far as I know, there is no known closed formula; a [recent (2010) thesis](http://research-repository.st-andrews.ac.uk/handle/10023/945) gives the number of non-isomorphic, non-anti-isomorphic semigroups with $9$ elements as 52,989,400,714,478.

Comment: See also the OEIS: [number of associative binary operations on an $n$-set](http://oeis.org/A023814), and [number of nonisomorphic, non-anti-isomorphic semigroups with $n$ elements](http://oeis.org/A001423).

Comment: @ArturoMagidin: Thanks for the references.

Comment: @spohreis: On this site, Doug Spoonwood once asked whether the proportion of associative binary operations to total operations approached $0$ as $n$ gets large. I gave an answer that you can [find here.](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/is-the-ratio-of-associative-binary-operations-to-all-binary-operations-on-a-set)  But the estimate I gave is very weak, just enough to show that the limit is $0$.

Comment: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/110211/how-many-binary-operations-are-associative

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Unlike the example you give (of commutative binary operations), there is no closed formula for the number of associative binary operations on a finite set.

A *semigroup* is a set with an associative binary operation. In what follows I will write "semigroup" rather than "associative binary operation".

It is shown in

> [Kleitman, Daniel J.; Rothschild, Bruce R.; Spencer, Joel H. The number of semigroups of order n.
>   Proc. Amer. Math. Soc. 55 (1976), no. 1, 227–232.](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2041879?origin=crossref&seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)

that almost all semigroups of order $n$ are $3$-nilpotent, and in Theorem 2.1(i) of

> [Distler, Andreas; Mitchell, J. D.
>   The number of nilpotent semigroups of degree 3.
>   Electron. J. Combin. 19 (2012), no. 2, Paper 51, 19 pp.](http://arxiv.org/abs/1201.3529)

that the number of $3$-nilpotent semigroups of order $n$ is:
\begin{equation}
\sigma(n)=\sum_{m=2}^{a(n)}{n \choose m}m\sum_{i=0}^{m-1}(-1)^i{m-1 \choose
  i}(m-i)^{\left((n-m)^2\right)}
\end{equation}
where $a(n)=\left\lfloor n+1/2-\sqrt{n-3/4}\,\right\rfloor$.

So, $\sigma(n)$ is approximately the number of distinct associative binary operations on a set of size $n$.

The value $\sigma(n)$ appears to converge very quickly to the number $\tau(n)$ of semigroups with $n$ elements:
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{l|llllllll}
n&1&2&3&4&5&6&7&8\\\hline
\tau(n)& 1& 8& 113& 3492& 183732& 17061118& 7743056064& 148195347518186\\
\sigma(n)&0& 0& 6& 180& 11720& 3089250& 5944080072& 147348275209800
\end{array}
\end{equation}
So, by $n=8$, the ratio $\sigma(n)/\tau(n)>0.994$.