# Is there any efficient algorithm for computing all semigroups of order n?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, semigroups

I found a [paper](https://www.irif.univ-paris-diderot.fr/~jep/PDF/Rio.pdf), but here the author solves a bit different problem.
My question is: Is there any efficient algorithm for computing all semigroups of order n?

Comment: So you don't just want to compute the **number** of semigroups, you want to compute the semigroups themselves? Meaning that you want your algorithm to generate a multiplication table for each and every semigroup of order $n$?

Comment: There are an awful lot of them, see OEIS A001423: 1, 1, 4, 18, 126, 1160, 15973, 836021, 1843120128, 52989400714478, ...

Comment: Have you tried the GAP software http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/semigroups.html

Comment: I think you would find many answers related to your question if the question would be in the http://cstheory.stackexchange.com

Comment: I don't understand the content of [this](https://scontent-frt3-1.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-xfa1/v/t34.0-12/13077205_532885916884090_1188593699_n.jpg?oh=9bb0636d629ae5d73a02ff0a407f4743&oe=571DD542) algorithm. What here does mean the 5-th line ( **if** v(ua[i]) is new  ) ?

Answer (score 2):

There is no efficient algorithm for computing all the semigroups of order $n$. The number of semigroups of order 10 is not even known (up to isomorphism and anti isomorphism). This is an extremely hard problem, and the number of semigroups grows very very quickly.

Almost all semigroups of any given size are 3-nilpotent, meaning that the product of any three elements is some fixed element 0, and that there is a product of two elements that is not 0. Arguably these semigroups are not very interesting.

See my answer [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/105438/80190) where I answer a similar question.

A library of all semigroups with order at most 8 (again up to isomorphism and anti isomorphism) is available in the GAP package [Smallsemi](http://www.gap-system.org/Packages/smallsemi.html).

Comment: But the following paper gives a bit efficient algorithm for computing, Isn't it possible to compute for n>=10 by this algorithm?
[Associative Binary Operations on a Set with Five Elements Amit Sehgal, Ravinder Kumar, Ombir Dahiya](http://research.ijcaonline.org/volume76/number6/pxc3890725.pdf)

Comment: It reduces the operations of computing in a few times.

Comment: It is the complexity of the problem which is important, as mentioned by another commenter, this is just a hard problem.

Comment: The approach used to compute the number of semigroups of order 9 is much more sophisticated than the method in the paper you cite.

Comment: Thanks James for your answer here and on TCS.