# How to choose a proper binary operation in a semigroup?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

I am interested in generating a finite commutative semigroup which is not a group.

And by generating I mean choosing a number $n$ (number of elements in a semigroup) and then defining a $n \times n$ matrix whose $a_{i,j}$ entry represents a result of my binary operation between $i$-th and $j$-th elements.

So what would be the properties of the matrix in question? Commutativity obviously implies that the matrix is symmetric. What about associativity and it not being a group?

Comment: Write down all possible binary operations on a two-element set. Which are commutative? Which are semigroups? Which are groups?

Comment: ($\mathbb{Z}/n,*)$ is an example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To test if it's a group, check:

1. If the values of some row agree with the values of the header; if so you've found the identity, and
2. Does the identity appear as an entry in each row?  If not, some element is missing an inverse.

Testing associativity is harder.  Associative relations are [rare](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/is-the-ratio-of-associative-binary-operations-to-all-binary-operations-on-a-set).

You may be interested in [this](http://www.jstor.org/discover/10.2307/2041879?uid=3739560&uid=4578661317&uid=2&uid=3&uid=3739256&uid=60&sid=21102116003583) result, which gives the matrix a type of block structure, for "almost all" semigroups.

On p.9 of [this](http://www.combinatorics.org/ojs/index.php/eljc/article/view/v19i2p51/pdf) they give a simple construction of nilpotent semigroups of degree 2 or 3, which is also "almost all" semigroups.

Comment: I appreciate all the information. However, since I'm struggling a little bit with the programming aspect of it, maybe by any chance you could write any particular binary operation which meets the requirements?

Comment: @Pranasas: did you see Martin Brandenburg's comment? If you just want other examples of commutative semigroups, you could also consult Grillet's book _Commutative Semigroups_. It's not clear from your question if your goal is to test a random binary operation for being a commutative semigroup or if want generate one that is "random enough" and has the desired properties.