# how fast does the proportion of associative operations on $S$ decrease with |$S$|?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, transcendental-numbers

as doubtless many have done before me, i recently fell into wondering how many of the binary operations on a finite set are associative. the stackexchange software fortunately pointed me to this discussion [Is the Ratio of Associative Binary Operations to All Binary Operations on a Set of $n$ Elements Generally Small?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/45648/is-the-ratio-of-associative-binary-operations-to-all-binary-operations-on-a-set) before i could irritate people by submitting a duplicate question.

on that location André Nicolas provided a neat answer to Doug Spoonwood's enquiry concerning the limit as $n \to \infty$ of the *proportion* ($r_n$) of operations on a set of $n$ elements which are associative.

as André points out his estimate is sufficient to show $r_n \to 0$ but there is a lot of scope to use similar arguments to tighten it. in fact $r_n$ appears to drop very rapidly with $n$. suppose we define:
$$ \alpha_n = \sum_{j=1}^n r_j
$$
**Q1** is $\alpha_n$ a convergent sequence? (easy?)

**Q2** (harder?) if the answer to **Q1** is positive, and $\alpha = \lim_{n \to \infty} \alpha_n$, is $\alpha$ a Liouville number, hence transcendental?

Answer (score 1):

André arrives at a ratio $r_n=O(\frac1n)$ merely by checking if $1^2$ commutes with $1$. For "most" choices, we should be able to find $d$ elemends $k_1,\ldots, k_d$ that in most caes differe from their squares as soon as $n\gg 2d$. If for each of these we check if $k^2$ commutes with $k$, this should give us that $r_n=O(n^{-d})$.
So Q1 is alredy answered positively with $d=2$ (which may even be not too hard to handle explicitly with all special cases).