# Does the percentage of associative operations on a finite set decrease monotonically towards zero?

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, semigroups, associativity, magma

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/46089) answer, André Nicolas proves that it is rare for a binary operation on a finite set to be associative, in the following sense: if $A_n$ denotes the number of semigroups that can be defined on a set with $n$ elements, and $B_n$ denotes the number of magmas that can be defined on a set with $n$ elements, then $A_n/B_n\to0$ as $n\to\infty$. (NB for the purposes of this question, two magmas are considered to be the same if they are set-theoretically equal; simply being isomorphic or anti-isomorphic is not enough.)

In the original question, it is asked whether the sequence $(A_n/B_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is monotonically decreasing, but as far as I can tell, this has not been answered. Is this the case?

Comment: As Andre says:"Monotonicity does not follow from the bound on the ratio. Your conjecture about monotonicity is however undoubtedly correct. "

Comment: @DietrichBurde: Right. I thought it was very likely that the statement is true simply by looking up the values of $A_n/B_n$ for small $n$. As for proving it, however, I feel that we must compute a lower bound for $A_n/B_n$; if this is greater than an upper bound for $A_{n+1}/B_{n+1}$, then we are done. Or are there other approaches?

Comment: That could work. There are a many, many, many other approaches that could work too, as one observes from looking at the many, many, many existing inequality proofs in mathematics. I would hate to mislead you by saying that THIS approach or THAT approach is the one that you should follow.